# Create edit forms SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, custom-form

I have a proble while create a new edit form in SharePoint Online, it throws me this error:

"Cannot save changes of list in the server"

[image: Cannot save changes of list in the server]

Beside, doing a little research, i found this:

It basicly said that i don't have the right permissions to do that, but i have total control in the site, i'm in the Owners group.

"
You don't have permissions to do this operation. Ask to the administrator of the site to change your permissions and try again, or sign in with another account with the rigth permissions. To sign in with another account, click in 'accept'
"
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a post in the Microsoft 365 Admin Center which may explain why. Microsoft have deprecated the creation of new forms through SharePoint designer.

[Link to post if you have access](https://admin.microsoft.com/Adminportal/Home#MessageCenter?id=MC210713)

> We’ve identified an issue that affects SharePoint Designer
>   functionality for creating custom Forms within SharePoint Online.
>
> We identified a code issue with an Application Programming Interface
>   (API) associated with creating new Forms through SharePoint Designer
>   that could cause impact to data integrity. We’ve confirmed that no
>   customers have been affected by the code issue; however, through
>   careful analysis we’ve determined that any changes to fix the issue
>   would likely impact other core service components. **In order to
>   maintain our data integrity standards we’ve expedited the deprecation
>   of this feature effective as of 3:00 AM UTC on Saturday, April 25,
>   2020**. This change only affects the action of creating new Forms and does not impact the ability to edit previously created Forms.
>
> After this change was made, users may have received the error: "Could
>   not save the list changes to the server," when creating new Forms.
>
> Creating Forms using SharePoint Designer is a legacy feature and we
>   recommend users who were leveraging this functionality to now use
>   PowerApps for this purpose. PowerApps is an easy and powerful tool
>   that allows users operating in the SharePoint Online Modern experience
>   to create and edit custom Forms for SharePoint lists and document
>   libraries right from a browser window. PowerApps does not require
>   traditional coding knowledge or any additional app downloads such as
>   InfoPath.
>
> *Note: SharePoint Online Classic users will need to temporarily switch to the Modern experience to access and utilize PowerApps; though, all
>   custom Forms created in PowerApps are accessible by SharePoint Online
>   Classic experience users.

Answer (score 0):

Does anybody have some workaround? I have tried to create an asp page reporting the parameters (list id etc) but so far I did not succeed